# Using strategy pattern in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Im trying to implement the strategy pattern in my crawler, I think it would be neat to use different strategies for crawling different websites. So I want whats inside `page.evaluate` to be different depending on which website is currently running. The commented code inside page.evaluate works, but is there a way I can extract this into a function? I have tried to run `this.findJobs()` with no success.

```
"use strict";

var Crawler = function() {
    this.page = require('webpage').create();
    this.website = "";
    this.jobs_list = [];

};

Crawler.prototype.setStrategy = function(company) {
    this.website = company;
};

Crawler.prototype.findJobData = function() {
    return this.website.findJobData();
};

Crawler.prototype.collectJobData = function() {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) { console.log(msg) };

    page.open('URL', function (status) {
        page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
            var temp_jobs = page.evaluate(this.findJobs());

                /*
                var jobs = [];
                var job;
                    $('ul.job-list').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('li').each(function(){
                        var job_link = $(this).find('a');
                        var url = "URL" + job_link.attr("href");
                        var location = $(this).find('span').text();

                        job = {title: job_link.text(), url: url, location: location, description: ""}
                        jobs.push(job);
                        console.log(job.title, job.url, job.location);
                    })
                });
                return jobs;*/
            console.log(temp_jobs[0].title)

            phantom.exit(0);
        });
    });

};

var strategy_a = function() {

    this.findJobs = function() {
            var jobs = [];
            var job;
            $('ul.job-list').each(function(){
                $(this).find('li').each(function(){
                    var job_link = $(this).find('a');
                    var url = "URL" + job_link.attr("href");
                    var location = $(this).find('span').text();

                    job = {title : job_link.text(), url : url, location : location, description : ""};
                    jobs.push(job);
                    console.log(job.title, job.url, job.location);
                })
            });
            return jobs;
    };
};


var strategy_a = new strategy_a();
var crawler = new Crawler();

crawler.setStrategy(strategy_a);
crawler.collectJobData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

- You meant to use `page.evaluate(this.findJobs);` instead of `page.evaluate(this.findJobs());` and
- `this` inside of the `page.includeJs` callback is not a reference to a `Crawler` instance.

This should work:

```
Crawler.prototype.collectJobData = function() {
    var page = this.page;
    var self = this;
    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) { console.log(msg) };

    page.open('URL', function (status) {
        page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
            var temp_jobs = page.evaluate(self.website.findJobs);
            console.log(temp_jobs[0].title)

            phantom.exit(0);
        });
    });
};
```

Note that you've generated multiple pages without using all of them, so I removed the second `require('webpage').create()`.

Comment: I get the following error when I run your code :/ TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.website.findJobs')

  undefined:2
  :3

Comment: Your `Crawler.prototype.findJobData` function is useless, because the specific `findJobs` function must be set to operate in the page context directly. You cannot use `findJobData` to do a proxy for `findJobs`, because `page.evaluate` is sandboxed and does not allow for references outside of the page context. Anyway, I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.